parsing sql using sqlGlot
I am trying to the column names, table name from a given query. On simpler queries, I am able to get them. But, for this query where the timestamp looks to be in UTC format, it is complaining. Doesn't like "T23" (it underlines this..when seen from a terminal).
Can anyone please help in how I can parse SQLs that has this type of timestamp?
>>> from sqlglot import parse_one, exp
q = 'SELECT Info,Type,Username FROM MyTbl WHERE EventDate >= 2024-03-20T23:45:43.216000+00:00 AND EventDate <= 2024-03-21T00:50:00.637052+00:00 ORDER BY EventDate DESC LIMIT 10000'
column_list = []


>>> for column in parse_one(q).find_all(exp.Column):
...     col = column.alias_or_name
...     column_list.append(col)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sri/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/ve_3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/__init__.py", line 139, in parse_one
    result = dialect.parse(sql, **opts)
  File "/Users/sri/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/ve_3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/dialects/dialect.py", line 503, in parse
    return self.parser(**opts).parse(self.tokenize(sql), sql)
  File "/Users/sri/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/ve_3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/parser.py", line 1170, in parse
    return self._parse(
  File "/Users/sri/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/ve_3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/parser.py", line 1239, in _parse
    self.raise_error("Invalid expression / Unexpected token")
  File "/Users/sri/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/ve_3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/parser.py", line 1280, in raise_error
    raise error
sqlglot.errors.ParseError: Invalid expression / Unexpected token. Line 1, Col: 69.
  SELECT Info,Type,Username FROM MyTbl WHERE EventDate >= 2024-03-20T23:45:43.216000+00:00 AND EventDate <= 2024-03-21T00:50:00.637052+00:00 ORDER BY EventDate DESC LIMIT 
>>> 


You're missing quotes around the timestamps.
One option is, you can use double quotes around the entire string and single quote the timestamps.
Another option is to keep the single quotes around the entire string and escape single quotes around the timestamps with \'.
See below.
q = "SELECT Info,Type,Username FROM MyTbl WHERE EventDate >= '2024-03-20T23:45:43.216000+00:00' AND EventDate <= '2024-03-21T00:50:00.637052+00:00' ORDER BY EventDate DESC LIMIT 10000"

q = 'SELECT Info,Type,Username FROM MyTbl WHERE EventDate >= \'2024-03-20T23:45:43.216000+00:00\' AND EventDate <= \'2024-03-21T00:50:00.637052+00:00\' ORDER BY EventDate DESC LIMIT 10000'

Printing 'column_list' yields:
['Info', 'Type', 'Username', 'EventDate', 'EventDate', 'EventDate']
